# Notices for ios app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am a novice developer ios so much, do not judge.

My question is whether the framework of such notices or make them yourself?
You can please link to them?

[image]

Comment: Are these notifications meant to be triggered remotely, or are they notifications about user error or something like that? Describe more how you want to use them.

Comment: That's just a UIView with a red backgroundImage, two UILabels, and a UIImageView. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by "Notices."

If you mean the UI that you've shown above, you can try the YRDropdownView framework here:
https://github.com/onemightyroar/YRDropdownView

If you mean handling notifications shared throughout the app, then use NSNotificationCenter:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You might consider checking out my library, [ALAlertBanner](https://github.com/alobi/ALAlertBanner). It allows you to show banners similar to the one in your screenshot and it's pretty easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

There's push notifications, and then there's local notifications.  I'd recommend taking a look at Apple's documentation to start.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html